# How can I add a text description to a KeyValuePair List?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> levels = new List<int>();
        List<int> indexs = new List<int>();
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (TreeNode node in advancedTreeView1.Nodes)
            {
                ListNodes(node, 1);
            }
        }

        void ListNodes(TreeNode node, int depthLevel)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode subnode in node.Nodes)
            {
                ListNodes(subnode, depthLevel);
            }
                levels.Add(node.Level);
                indexs.Add(node.Index);

                myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(node.Level, node.Index));
        }
    }
}
```

In the end I see in the myList key and value for example :

```
0, 1
0, 4
3, 0
2, 1
```

Left side is the level right side is the index
But what I want to add is a description for my self so when debugging using a break point and watching the List I will see something like :

```
Level = 0, Index = 1
Level = 0, Index = 4
Level = 3, Index = 0
Level = 2, Index = 1
```

So it will be easier to remember what is the level and what is the index.

This is how I solved it. Not the best way but it's working:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dialog_System
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> levels = new List<int>();
        List<int> indexs = new List<int>();
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (TreeNode node in advancedTreeView1.Nodes)
            {
                ListNodes(node, 1);
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyvalues in myList)
            {
                int levelkey = Int32.Parse(keyvalues.Key.Substring(8));
                int indexvalue = Int32.Parse(keyvalues.Value.Substring(8));
            }
        }


        void ListNodes(TreeNode node, int depthLevel)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode subnode in node.Nodes)
            {
                ListNodes(subnode, depthLevel);
            }

                levels.Add(node.Level);
                indexs.Add(node.Index);

                myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                    "Level = " + node.Level.ToString(), "Index = " + node.Index.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: Or write a new class / struct with `Level` and `Index` properties.

Comment: You can write something like: `var myList = new List<(int Level, int Index)> { (10, 20) }; var result1 = myList[0].Level; var result2 = myList[0].Index;`. But it's a List of named tuples, not a `List<KeyValuePair<...>>`

Comment: I found how to do it. Maybe not the best way but it's working. Edited my question with the solution.